# How to simulate modifier key combination (Alt-Shift-P) in Capybara / Selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm using Selenium-webdriver within Capybara.

Is there a way to simulate pressing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `send_keys` method on an element.

```
my_element.send_keys [:alt, :shift, "p"]
```

or, if you want it on the page:

```
page.send_keys [:alt, :shift, "p"]
```

See: [`Capybara::Node::Element#send_keys`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FElement%3Asend_keys)

Comment: I went to the documentation but using page wouldn't work for me. Whether because I was within an iframe, I'm not sure.  Instead I use my_element as a visible element within that iframe and got it to work that way